# How to chain animations with different scaleEffect

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to do the following with Swift animation:

1. I have a circle with a *small* pulsating animation by default.
2. I want to **enlarge** the pulsating animation temporarily when an event is detected. But the animation should resume back to being small after 3 animation frames.

Here is my naive try at it.

```
Circle()
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    .scaleEffect(1 + scale)
    .foregroundColor(detected ? .red : .blue)
    .onAppear{
        withAnimation(.easeInOut.repeatForever()) {
            scale = 0.1
        }
    }
    .onChange(of: event_detected) { _ in
        withAnimation(.easeInOut.repeatCount(3)) {
            scale = 0.8
        }
        withAnimation(.easeInOut.repeatForever()) {
            scale = 0.1
        }
    }
```

My expected behavior is the pulsating circle gets smaller 3 animation frames after the detection of an event (the repeatCount(3)). However, what ends up happening is the animation stays the larger size, I guess somehow the repeatForever animation is running with the larger scaling factor. How do I fix this?

Comment: Look into `GeometryEffect`

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not sure how it can be done with GeometryEffect

Comment: https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part2/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to chain two animations with different scale factors. This is not possible at least in this case is not ideal, as Swift animations only support one scale factor at a time.

To fix this, you should create two separate animations, one for the small pulsating animation and one for the large pulsating animation. You can then use the .sequence() modifier to chain the two animations together.

Try something like this:

```
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    .foregroundColor(detected ? .red : .blue)
    .onAppear {
        // Set up the initial small pulsating animation
        withAnimation(.easeInOut.repeatForever()) {
            scale = 0.1
        }
    }
    .onChange(of: event_detected) { _ in
        // Stop the ongoing animation immediately without animation
        withAnimation(nil) {
            scale = 0.1
        }
        
        // Wait for a short duration before starting the large pulsating animation
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            // Start the large pulsating animation with a repeat count of 3
            withAnimation(.easeInOut.repeatCount(3)) {
                scale = 0.8
            }
        }
        
        // Wait for approximately 3.3 seconds before resuming the small pulsating animation
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.3) {
            // Resume the small pulsating animation
            withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                scale = 0.1
            }
        }
    }
```

1 - Add withAnimation(nil) before changing the scale value to 0.1 to prevent the initial scale change from animating.

2- Use DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter to schedule the sequential animations. We wait a short while before starting the large scale animation to make sure the small scale animation has time to stop completely.

3- Adjust the timings so that the large scale animation lasts about 3 seconds and the small scale animation resumes after 3.3 seconds.

This code will create two separate animations, one for the small pulsating animation and one for the large pulsating animation. The small pulsating animation will start immediately, and the large pulsating animation will start after 3 animation frames. After the large pulsating animation finishes, the small pulsating animation will resume.

Good luck

Comment: For some reason, the code snippet you gave didn't work. I'm still getting a large animation after. In addition, the delay doesn't do much besides stopping the animation entirely for 3.3 seconds (the circle just stops pulsating for 3.3s, then goes back to the larger animation).